# Creating Tags for Max / Min dates in Power BI DAX

Tags: filter, tags, dax, calculated-columns

I have the following table calculated table - QOL2:

In DAX Power BI I need to create a calculated columns RecentDate and LatestDate as shown on a screenshot:

Based on ClientID I need to tag latest date as "Max" in LatestDate column and earliest date as "Min" in [RecentDate] column (see screenshot)

If there is only one date (no highest or earliest date) - as it is for ClientID = 2666, then I need no tags!

[image]

I am using the following code, but it puts "Max" tag in RecentDate and "Min" tag in LatestDate:

```
      LatestDate = var LatestD = CALCULATE(Min(QOL2[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(QOL2, QOL2[ClientID]))   
                    return If(QOL2[Date]=LatestD && QOL2[Date]>1,"Min")  




     RecentDate = var RecentD = CALCULATE(Max(QOL2[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(QOL2,QOL2[ClientID]))                                                                                                                                                          
                   return If(QOL2[Date]=RecentD && QOL2[Date]>1,"Max")
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need this as Calculate column, but you can do this like that:

```
RecentDate = var _client = 'Table'[ClientID]
var _min = calculate(min('Table'[Date]), FILTER(ALL('Table'), _client = 'Table'[ClientID]))
var _max = calculate(max('Table'[Date]), FILTER(ALL('Table'), _client = 'Table'[ClientID]))
return
if(_client = 'Table'[ClientID] && _min = 'Table'[Date] && _max <> _min, "MIN", BLANK())

LatestDate = var _client = 'Table'[ClientID]
var _min = calculate(min('Table'[Date]), FILTER(ALL('Table'), _client = 'Table'[ClientID]))
var _max = calculate(max('Table'[Date]), FILTER(ALL('Table'), _client = 'Table'[ClientID]))
return
if(_client = 'Table'[ClientID] && _max = 'Table'[Date] && _max <> _min, "MAX", BLANK())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly!